# MATLAB: data points won't connect?

Tags: matlab, plot

I only have about two weeks of experience with programming/Matlab, so I'm just a beginner. In my code I would like to plot mu as a function of alpha. When I display mu it shows the 10 values of mu for each value of alpha. However, when I plot the graph it gives the values of mu as seperate points. But I want the points to be connected with just one line. How can I solve this problem?

```
n=40; %number of months
p=0.23; %probability of success
num_of_simulations=100;
s=rng; x = rand(1,n)<p;
rng(s);

hold on; 
for alpha=0.01:0.01:0.1;
    for i=1:num_of_simulations
        x = rand(1,n)<p;

        S0=5000; %initial value
        Y(1)=S0*alpha; %deposit

        for k=1
            if x(1,1)==1;
                S(1, i)=S0+2*Y(1);
            else
                S(1, i)=S0-Y(1);
            end
        end

        for k=2:n
            Y(k)=S(k-1, i)*alpha;
            if x(1,k)==1;
                S(k, i)=S(k-1, i)+2*Y(k);
            else
                S(k, i)=S(k-1, i)-Y(k);
            end
        end

        Sn(i)=S(n,i); %end value for each simulations
    end

    mu=mean(Sn);
    disp(mu);
    plot(alpha,mu);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your points aren't connected is because you plot each point separately. If we take a different approach and take `alpha = 0.01:0.01:0.1;` out of the `for` loop definition and then change the `for` loop definition to `for j=1:numel(alpha)` we can still loop over every element of `alpha`. Now we need to change each use of `alpha` in the loop to `alpha(j)` so that we are referring to the current element of `alpha` and not every element. Following on from this we need to change `mu` to `mu(j)`. What this means is that when the entire loop has finished we have all of the values of `alpha` and `mu` stored and 1 call to `plot(alpha, mu)` will plot the data with the points connected as in

[image: plot]

This also enables us to remove `hold on;` too as we only plot once.

I've included the complete edited code here for you to see. The changes are minuscule and should make sense.

```
clear all
close all

n = 40; %number of months
p = 0.23; %probability of success
num_of_simulations = 100;
s = rng;
x = rand(1, n) < p;
rng(s);

alpha = 0.01:0.01:0.1;

for j = 1:numel(alpha)

    for i = 1:num_of_simulations
        x = rand(1, n) < p;

        S0 = 5000; %initial value
        Y(1) = S0*alpha(j); %deposit


        for k = 1
            if x(1, 1) == 1;
                S(1, i) = S0 + 2*Y(1);
            else
                S(1, i) = S0 - Y(1);
            end
        end

        for k = 2:n
            Y(k) = S(k-1, i)*alpha(j);
            if x(1, k) == 1;
                S(k, i) = S(k-1, i) + 2*Y(k);
            else
                S(k, i) = S(k-1, i) - Y(k);
            end
        end

        Sn(i) = S(n, i); %end value for each simulations
    end

    mu(j) = mean(Sn);
    disp(mu(j));
end

plot(alpha, mu);
```